# My paragraph is not starting from the left side of my container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, paragraph

I created a container to hold my paragraph, but I can't seem to get it to start all the way on the left side of the container. It starts like 100px from the left side. I can't find what I am doing wrong.

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1C213D;
    background-image: url("background.png");
}

.nav{
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 5000px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, .4);
}

.nav-pills li a{
   /* 0.5s is the amount of time it take to change colors */
   transition: .3s background ease-in-out;
}

ul li{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: "Play";
    display: block;
    color: lightsteelblue;
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.main{
  }

p{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 265px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 54px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>  
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  </div>
  
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                    <img src="logo.png">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>        
            </ul>
      </div>
        <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-lg-offset-1  col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 main">
             <p>This is the home page.</p>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not using Bootstrap's [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) correctly: *Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding. Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns. Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.* You are placing columns directly inside containers instead of rows.

Comment: Could you post an example of how it should be?

Comment: I think it would make more sense for Michael Coker to update their answer than for me to post a new one that would mostly be the same except for the row/container issue. The link also has some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `.col-[size]-offset` classes will create that offset. Remove them and the paragraph will start at the left.

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1C213D;
    background-image: url("background.png");
}

.nav{
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 5000px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, .4);
}

.nav-pills li a{
   /* 0.5s is the amount of time it take to change colors */
   transition: .3s background ease-in-out;
}

ul li{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: "Play";
    display: block;
    color: lightsteelblue;
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.main{
  }

p{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 265px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 54px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>  
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  </div>
  
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                    <img src="logo.png">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>        
            </ul>
      </div>
        <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7 main">
             <p>This is the home page.</p>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! :)

Comment: @Lukie awesome, np

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all your Bootstrap file is not included properly
   append *http:* before your Bootstrap link.
2. Remove offset classes to get your paragraph on left side

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1C213D;
    background-image: url("background.png");
}

.nav{
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 5000px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, .4);
}

.nav-pills li a{
   /* 0.5s is the amount of time it take to change colors */
   transition: .3s background ease-in-out;
}

ul li{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: "Play";
    display: block;
    color: lightsteelblue;
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.main{
  }

p{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 265px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 54px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>  
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  </div>
  
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                    <img src="logo.png">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>        
            </ul>
      </div>
        <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7 main">
             <p>This is the home page.</p>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's those `col-xx-offset-1`'s.  If you remove those, your text sits against the left side (obeying padding and the `.container`, of course).

Corrected Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7 main">
        <p>This is the home page.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```